# How to Connect to S3 bucket using policy without keys through Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a policy something like

```
{
"Id":"Pid6",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": [
                     "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
                     "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
                    ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Java code to connect to S3 bucket is

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(Regions.region).build();
s3Client.putObject( new PutObjectRequest( S3_BUCKET, s3Path, file )
            .withCannedAcl( CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead ) );
```

I am able to connect to s3 using access key & secret key...
How can I connect to s3 bucket using policy without the need for key based access using Java.
I mean how to get `s3Client` object or `awsCreds` object using `policy.json` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an application running on an EC2 instance, you can attach the policy to an IAM Role and assign that role to the instance.  This way, you do not need to specify credentials for the application.

Assigning an IAM Role to an EC2 instance can be done during launch from the Console or through AWS CLI

Here is the full details from AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

> We designed IAM roles so that your applications can securely make API
>   requests from your instances, without requiring you to manage the
>   security credentials that the applications use.

Comment: if you use IAM Role for EC2, then you don't need to specify `withCredentials()` **at all**.  You specify the IAM role when you launch the instance.  for example `aws ec2 run-instances --iam-instance-profile Name=MyInstanceProfile --image-id ami-1a2b3c4d --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-groups MySecurityGroup`

Answer (score 0):

If EC2 has a role where it can write to S3 then

```
AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider=
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().asyncCredentialUpdateEnabled(Boolean.TRUE).build();
S3AsyncClient   client=S3AsyncClient.builder()
               .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider).build();
```

The InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider loads the credentials from instances metadata information. Please refer the documentation 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html